# Elastic search DSL Syntax equivalence for SQL statement

Tags: elasticsearch, tire, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to replicate the below query logic in an elastic search query but something's not right.

Basically the query below returns one doc. I'd like either the first condition to be applied: `"name": "iphone"` **OR** the more complex second one which is: `(username = 'gogadget' AND status_type = '1' AND created_time between 4532564 AND 64323238)`. Note that the *nested bool must* inside the should would take care of the more complex condition. I should still see 1 doc if I change the outside match of `"name": "iphone"` to be changed to `"name": "wrong value"`. But I get nothing when I do that. I'm not sure where this is wrong.

The SQL Query is here below.

```
SELECT * from data_points 
WHERE name = 'iphone'
    OR 
(username = 'gogadget' AND status_type = '1' AND created_time between 4532564 AND 64323238) 


{
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "minimum_should_match": "1",
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "username": "gogadget"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "status_type": [
                                                    "3",
                                                    "4"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "range": {
                                                "created_time": {
                                                    "gte": 20140712,
                                                    "lte": 1405134711
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": [],
                        "must_not": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "iphone"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your sql query returning?

Comment: sql query? That doesn't exist I'm just using it explain what I'm trying to do in elastic.

Comment: Ok. Then expected results?

Comment: @eliasah I've added more details to the question. I expected 1 doc to be returned. Please read the added section to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`should` query will match the query and return.

You don't need use `must` to aggregate your `OR query`.

The query should like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "username": "gogadget"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "terms": {
                            "status_type": [
                                "3",
                                "4"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "range": {
                            "created_time": {
                                "gte": 20140712,
                                "lte": 1405134711
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "name": "iphone"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```